# Why does calling entry.get() give me "invalid command name"?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my code:

```
def ask(what,why):
    root=Tk()
    root.title(why)
    label=Label(root,text=what)
    label.pack()
    entry=Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    button=Button(root,text='OK',command=root.destroy)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return entry.get()
```

And when I call the code:

```
print(ask('Name:','Hello!'))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gui.py", line 16, in <module>
    ask('Name:','Hello!')
  File "C:\gui.py", line 15, in ask
    return entry.get()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2520, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".48148176"
```

I am using Python 3.4.3 on 32-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

When you press the button, the application is destroyed, the `mainloop` ends, and you try to return the contents of an `Entry` widget... in an application that was destroyed. You need to save the contents of `entry` before destroying the application. Instead of hacking your way through this, it would be much better to set up a Tkinter application in the proper way, such as with an object-oriented approach.

```
class App:
    # 'what' and 'why' should probably be fetched in a different way, suitable to the app
    def __init__(self, parent, what, why):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(why)
        self.label = Label(self.parent, text=what)
        self.label.pack()
        self.entry = Entry(self.parent)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button = Button(parent, text='OK', command=self.use_entry)
        self.button.pack()
    def use_entry(self):
        contents = self.entry.get()
        # do stuff with contents
        self.parent.destroy() # if you must

root = Tk()
app = App(root, what, why)
root.mainloop()
```